# Customize default taglib prefix

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans, custom-component

I don't know if this has a solution or is an IDE enhancement, but, when I'm using primefaces components in Netbeans, the autocomplete suggest the taglib `p:...`, no matter the id is http://primefaces.org/ui (should suggest pou), but if you're using primefaces extensions instead give `pe` as the showcase, gives `poue`.

So, now, I created a custom tag lib with id http://zeitek.net/ui, but as extensions is suggested znu, I know I can change it manually, but since is a collaborative project, I would like to use ztk as the predefined prefix to keep the standard in the code, is there anyway to achieve this with a JSF parameter or Netbeans configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if someone need this, i was missing this:
You need to create a tag-lib like normal and add this param:

```
<facelet-taglib
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0"
id="zinf">
<namespace>http://zeitek.net/infraction/jsf/ui</namespace>
<composite-library-name>zinf</composite-library-name>
```

The last part is the important one: **< composite-library-name>zinf< /composite-library-name>**